# JSON decode a single array

Tags: json

I have an array like this:

```
Array st = [[234,412,42]]
```

Does anyone know who to get JSON decode code which give `[234,412,42]`? (The inner array).

The output should looks like this `[234,412,42]`. In Java

Comment: In that case you can get that element with `st[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just decode the whole thing and then get the 1st element of the outer array

```
// Quasi-code
var innerArray = decodedObject[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

pick on : http://www.json.org/
about array :
A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

so You will get an array of array

(RFC 4627: json)